# Adding checkbox selected values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ykLrnntf/). How can I add each selected row as an array into the `data []` so that it looks like this:

```
[{"Cell phone":"BlackBerry Bold 9650","Rating":"2/5","Location":"UK"},
{"Cell phone":" Samsung Galaxy","Rating":"3/5","Location":"US"}]
```

Here is the code I have:

```
var data = [];
function myfunc(ele) {

 var values = new Array();
       $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
              function () {
                   values.push($(this).text());
              });

       alert("val---" + values.join (", "));
 }


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.case").click(myfunc);
});
```

Comment: your fiddle works fine what is problem?

Comment: Do you want `data.push($(this).text())` instead of `values.push($(this).text())`?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for reply but what I want is having an array of arrays storing in data[]

Answer (score 0):

check if this works,

here is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o8yj6g68/)

```
var data = [];
function myfunc(ele) {

 var values = [];
 var keys = [];
   $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("table").find('th'),
          function () {
              keys.push($(this).text());
          });

 keys.shift(); // to remove the first key
 var len = keys.length, obj={}, ctr=0;
   $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
          function () {
                obj[keys[ctr]]=$(this).text();
                ctr++;
                if(ctr==len){
                    values.push(obj);
                    obj={};
                    ctr=0;
                }

          });

   alert("val---" + JSON.stringify(values));
 }


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.case").click(myfunc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ugdas2em/

Try this:

```
var data =  {};
function myfunc(ele) {

    //var values = new Array();
    var k = 0;
    var j = 0;
    data[k] =  {};
    $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"),
                 function () {  
                     if(j==3)
                     {
                          k = k+1;
                          data[k] =  {};             
                          j = 0;
                     }                 
                     //values.push($(this).text());
                     data[k][j] = $(this).text();
                     j=j+1;

                  });

           console.debug(data);    
           //alert("val---" + values.join (", "));
     }


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.case").click(myfunc);
});
```

Note: If you want then you can use [] with data variable in place of {} in my code. You need to replace at three place. Thanks.